# How to put key words or meta tags on app when publishing to android market

Tags: android

I do not see a means to put key words or meta tags on an app when publishing it to the android market. Is there a way to do this?  Such that if one builds an app for the physical therapy industry a PT an search PT. The current search only seems to search the app title.

Comment: A similar question has this good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11000904/847235

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I put meta keywords in application description in Play Console. The search searches app title and description.

Example: [image]

Comment: can you send an example  android:description = " wordOne wordTwo"  or do you comma separate them?

Comment: I do it in the Android Market description field. 
Description (en_US): 
Totally useless app. Keywords: app, useless, android

Comment: Oh! you mean in the android manifest file ? got it. Please edit your answer to include a example and the fact that it needs to go in the manifest file. Else its easily confused with the google play console account.

Comment: @krtek, now I get it. Thanks will try it out. U had my upvote.

Answer (score -1):

i added a keyword portion as krtek suggests. I hope this is okay to do and not frowned upon like putting keywords at the bottom of a web page for search engines to "find".
http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/4403/screenshottn.png