# android app keywords

Tags: android

I've already added my app to google play, I used the android develop console and everything is right.

But right now you only can access to my app using the name, but I would like to add some keywords, and my app apears easily.

how can I do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google automatically picks up keyword from your title and app description. However, adding something like `Keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3` to your description is considered keyword spamming by Google, especially if you add the title, or the developer name of a competing app. Instead, try to include your keywords in the description in a natural manner.

Comment: I did that but it dosent work , did you know the reason

Comment: @MinaFawzy did you found any solution for this ?

Comment: yes I add keywords on app description separated by semi columns "word," after each word and its working it may take some time to appear on search but it will be working

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you choose the right category for your app forexample if it is a riddles app, it would be best to choose the trivia category where users will easily access yo product. i also do agree with user1256477 that choosing the right keywords forexample words like brain teaser will some how help.

Here is a link that may be of help.

Feel free to check out the description on my app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dogmaz.mindtwist