# Can i add tags to an application in google play console?

Tags: android, tags, manifest, google-play, application-name

I wrote an application named *"Bio View"*, if I search for my application in `Google Play`, it does not show up, instead if I search *BlueSkyBio* (the "appname" variable from the manifest is named that way), i can find my app.

```
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <string name="app_name">BlueSkyBio</string>
```

My question is, how can i add tags to my application, like: `bio`, `view`, `bioview`, etc. So that I will be sure people can find it ?

Comment: you can put them in your description. But there is no real "tags" concept on the Android market. And furthermore the search algorithm is somewhat of a black box, it takes many things into consideration when picking the order of results which is why a search for your exact application name will not always result in your app being at the top (or even near the top) of the list of results.

Comment: See this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11000904/847235

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There now appears to be a Tags option in the Google Play Console, but they are predefined tags to choose from, so it's pretty limited, but may help some people finding this question:
[Play Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLcFa.png)

Comment: I have modified this to be the correct Answer, because it is more up to date that the initial "accepted answer" + It has data about where to find and also a screenshot

Answer (score 16):

FoamyGuy has answered on a comment for my question:
  you can put them in your description. But there is no real "tags" concept on the Android market. And furthermore the search algorithm is somewhat of a black box, it takes many things into consideration when picking the order of results which is why a search for your exact application name will not always result in your app being at the top (or even near the top) of the list of results. – FoamyGuy Apr 5 at 14:34

Comment: If we add tags/keywords in descriptions then they will be visible to users. Is there any way we can add tags without showing to users..

Comment: @Mukesh Garg unfortunately we cannot. In the app store you can but the google play demand the developers to think hard on a real description/app name/subtitle in order to prevent spamming. (spamming - set deceiving tags just to gain a better ranking to your app)

Comment: I did not get clearly...If we spam some words  on description for better result on search effect result or not?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Google has introduced this option now. You can add tags in google play console under

> Store Presence -> Store Listing -> Manage Tags

Answer (score 0):

you can add your keywords in description

Example

```
Keywords: leaynik, SOS, eyes, l3ynik, la3yink
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

seems my way is old now and google play add Tags
according to @patrickbadley answer

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about description in PlayStore listing? Or is there description somewhere in the app's apk?

Comment: yea app description

Comment: I did what you said (keywords in description, which list similar games) and my app got reject. Google sent me an email said: "We don't allow apps with misleading, improperly formatted, non-descriptive, irrelevant, excessive, or inappropriate metadata, including but not limited to the app's description, developer name, title, icon, screenshots, and promotional images. Developers must provide a clear and well-written description of their app and avoid using repetitive or unrelated keywords or references. We also don't allow unattributed or anonymous user testimonials in the app's description.".

Comment: Thanks for mention that I update my answer according to the new update from  patrickbadley