# App not in search results on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app on Google Play two days ago.  If I search for it by name ("1-on-1 Poker"), I find it, but if I search by term ("poker"), it's not displayed.  [Apologies to those that think I'm looking for free publicity, but the exact name of the app is relevant to this question]

This has obviously resulted in no one knowing about my app, although it seems like it's available to be downloaded from testing on a few devices.

I asked Google, but all they said was, "We do the best we can with search.  Sometimes apps don't show up for a certain term".  This seems like an odd answer.

Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Take a look at the answer for this SO post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836577/can-i-add-tags-to-an-application-in-google-play-console

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: having similar issue 126 Astrology is not in the list when searched with Astrology keyword

Comment: Having the same problem, maybe they do it purposely to make us pay for ads, which I have done, so if that's what it is, well played Google, well played. PS, ads didn't help either.

Comment: Similar issue for [SwipePad - One Swipe Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.conduction.swipepad.android) which has 1,000,000+ installs btw

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165

Answer (score 32):

This is not that uncommon an experience.  I think your app doesn't have enough unique keywords in the name, so it is not showing up.

My app also uses very common words ("Droid Of The Day").  For the longest time, I didn't show up in search results at all (I would search my name, and go through all 20 pages of results, and never see my app). Each of the words in my name were being ignored I think, as they weren't unique).

Bottom line, I didn't want to change my name, so I suffered a bit (until I hit a critical mass of downloads, and so my search rank went higher).

You can change your name in the Play Store Console, so I would suggest trying some different combinations of words, and try to find some that are unique to yourself (maybe 'Poker Wars' or something).

There is a tool on AppBrains (http://www.appbrain.com/apptimizer‎) that allows you to search any app (check your competitors ;-), and see a ranking of search terms.  I would suggest you check this out, and use their suggestions to figure out how you can make your name more unique, while still getting your message across.

Bottom-line, I think your name doesn't have enough 'uniqueness', and that is why it is not showing up in search ranks.

Comment: How many downloads did it take for you to show up?  I have the same problem and I'm going to have to market my app to get anyone to download it so I want to know what that breaking point will be.

Comment: I actually contacted someone at Google and had my app name White-listed.  I don't think you can rely on reaching a certain download threshold to see your app, but would be better served finding a name that is unique.  To be clear, I don't think this problem will resolve itself with a high number of downloads (my app actually had hundreds of thousands of downloads and still couldn't be found)

Comment: Well I mean is contacting google and having them fix it an option?  Can I expect my app to be ranked higher at that point as far as search is concerned?  Also How did you get that many downloads without even being visible in a search?

Comment: I had a friend at Google, so I think this is not an option for most people.  I worked hard to find downloads (through a variety of methods).  An important way to drive search visibility is get people to link to your play store listing (incoming links to Play store will improve visibility).  There are tons of ways to optimize your listing and visibility (but that is for another SO question I think)

Comment: @Booger: How did you contact? Can you share the link please?

Comment: There is a link (big ?) in the top of the Play Store console. That is best place for sure.  Is how I would do this.

Comment: I am having the same issue. My app name is "whipster" and if you search for "whipster" about 15 to 20 other apps with "whisper" in the name show up first. This is causing massive problems because our users are searching for "whipster" and not seeing it as the 1st result, and by seeing "whisper" apps they are thinking that ours doesn't even exist. If you search for "abc" and "abf" shows up, a user thinks "abc" doesn't exist and google is simply just offering up the next closest thing  and therefore never scroll to find it...but they would if they scrolled 4 pages down.

Comment: @rollinger I would suggest contacting Play Support via the tool in the console - I bet they will be able to fix this for you.

Comment: here it's the form if you are having problems https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en#ts=3056735

Comment: my app is quite and of course unique... but still not shown.... :'(

Comment: From what I can see uniqueness doesn't enter into it. If you search for 'timer', apps called 'Timer' and 'Clock' appear in the search. My app name is 'EasyTimer' yet it doesn't appear. 'EasyTimer' is more unique than 'timer', so this disproves the notion that uniqueness is a significant determinant.

Comment: That doesn't prove anything, I think "Easy" and "Timer" and NOT unique words.  Neither of them are particularly unique (so I think this DOES prove my original point still)

Answer (score 8):

**You will not able to find the app when searching by its name in Google Play Store because your application is not ranked against google distribution servers.**

> The Play Store is not as easy as we think it is. So these are some
> things to implement if you want success...

First of all, Remember that **Google won't push your app to the top** until you've had more reviews and downloads than your competitors. There are a few things you can do to try and improve your position.

1. Try to get a more **unique name for your App** (But must contain a keyword).
2. Get as many friends and family members as you can to **download and review your app**.
3. Use the name a few times in the description of your app.
4. Improve the text in your app description and info sections on the listing.
5. Give it some time and perform **ASO (APP Store Optimization)**
6. Promote your application across different platforms like **Blogs, youtube, Facebook pages.**
7. Use ad services like google ads or Facebook ads to gain organic users.

I published an application with a unique name [Home Workout without Equipment](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeworkoutapp.noequipmentworkout) one month back and It's ranked with the help of ASO and proper keywords. It has 1000+ reviews and 50,000+ downloads in a short period of time.

So remember….

(Formula for my success)

[ASO + App Markeetring + Reviews = App Ranking](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tulip.weather)
[ASO+ AM+ R = AR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tulip.weather)

Play store rank apps on top based on good ASO and deep links associated with apps along with downloads and reviews. (Always remember to gain organic users)

Comment: it appears on left side of answer at the beginning.

Comment: "not able to find the app when searching by its name" - I wonder, if I were looking for a definition of concrete word in an online dictionary, and instead of the answer, I would get something like "sorry, we can't give the definition of this word, because this word is rarely searched in our dictionary"...

Comment: HaHaHa.. Keep looking :p

Answer (score -1):

If you've ever installed the app through Google's Play Store (or alpha/beta channels), and are logged in when on the play store, Google will filter the results and not show your app.

You can confirm this by opening up an incognito browser window, going to the play store, and search for your app.

Comment: That's simply not true.

Comment: Its so true, I was banging my head around for quite some time and this answer served me right.

Comment: It seems to be behaving in described way for me as well.

Answer (score -5):

Try searching it by id of your app,
refer config.xml of your application

Comment: doesn't seem to address the real question