# Android app is not listed when searched by name and the required permissions are not shown when downloading

Tags: android, seo, google-play

I just published my first android application to google play. Even though the application was successfully accepted, i'm still facing couple of problems when listing and downloading app through the google play.

First of them is that the permissions required to run the application is not mentioned when downloading the app even though i have added three permissions in the manifest file as shown below. When downloading the app it says, no special permissions are required to download the application.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pathfinder.examcountdown"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.skydrive.examcountdown.ExamCountdownMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The second question is that when i search the application by app name, it is not listed. Of course i don't expect it to be the first app that is listed since, there are no downloads yet. But it is not listed anywhere within the results. Its get listed only when i search by the package name. Is this normal?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903746/1239966

The search algorithm is somewhat of a black box, it takes many things into consideration when picking the order of results which is why a search for your exact application name will not always result in your app being at the top (or even near the top) of the list of results.

So, please make sure to include enough details in description, add multiple screenshots, videos to show up higher in the ranking. Also, if the app has a unique name, it'll show up higher in the search results.

Regarding permissions, if android asks for correct permissions when installing the app on the device, everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. The thing is that the name of my application is "Exam Countdown". When the app is searched as it is it will not be listed. But when it is searched without the space in the middle as one word, it is listed. What is the reason for that.

Comment: It is listed when you search without spaces because the package name of your app contains 'examcountdown'.